# Changing distance between LI items, which belong to different _classes_

Tags: html, css

How can I increase the distance between **Text_2** and **Text_4** *without* changing the distance between **Text_2** and **Text_3**?
**Text_2** and **Text_4** belong to *one* class, while **Text_3** - to *another*.
**UPDATE:** the code should apply margin to ALL items related to `.example` class - not only the "last-child" one, or the "2nd" one.
I tried `.not` selector: `ol.circle ul > li:not(.example_translated)` but it's not working for some reason...

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q36ugnjy/1/)

```css
.meanings_and_examples {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.meaning {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #1f2c60;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
}

.example {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #5d78e5;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.example_translated {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #4b5ea7;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

ol.circle {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 3em;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

li {
  line-height: calc(1em + 1.5vw);
}

ol.circle>li {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

ol.circle>li::before {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-1.73em);
  content: counter(item);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

li::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  height: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1f2c60;
  left: -2.2em;
  top: 0.05em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="meaning">
  <ol class="circle">
    <li>Text_1</li>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="example">Text_2</span></li>
      <li><span class="example_translated">Text_3</span></li>
      <li><span class="example">Text_4</span></li>
    </ul>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: @MrLister - no, between Text_2 and Text_4 exactly. Imagine: there's no Text_3, so Text_4 becomes _immediately_ under Text_2 and there's a certain space between them. I want to increase this space, however, when Text_3 comes _back_ the space between Text_2 and Text_3 will not differ from the _current_ one.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The `ul` should be **inside** the `li`. You closed the `li` too soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this situation you can use multiple ways

**Way 1:**

```
ol.circle ul > li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

**Way 2**

```
ol.circle ul > li:last-child {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

**Way 3**

```
ol.circle li > span.example_translated {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display:block;
}
```

**For general solution use for jQuery code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            jQuery('.example_translated').parent('li').css('margin-bottom', '30px');
});
```

Comment: thank you, it works in general, however your code applies margin to either item with _exact number_ or to the _last one_, while i want it to be applied to ALL items related to `.example` class. Is that possible?

Comment: Isn't it possible to use CSS means only? There's a `.not` selector, which i tried to use (see my UPDATE to the initial question), but its not working for some reason. Maybe i placed it in a wrong place?

Comment: Than use Way 3. Because we can't find parent li using child class.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this css**

```
.meaning ol.circle ul li:last-child {margin-top: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this CSS

```
.circle ul li:last-child {margin-top: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit and comment, you want to have an empty line between two list items that have `example` spans in them, even if there is no list item with an `example_translated` span in between.

That is not possible with CSS alone, given the current HTML.
But it can be done if you assign the classes directly to the list items instead of the spans.
I.e. `<list class="..."><span>` instead of `<list><span class="...">`.

I added a new entry to your example that doesn't have the middle li, so you can see that this does what you want.

```css
.meanings_and_examples {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.meaning {
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #1f2c60;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
}

.example span {  /* changed */
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #5d78e5;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.example_translated span {  /* changed */
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  color: #4b5ea7;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

ol.circle {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 3em;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

li {
  line-height: calc(1em + 1.5vw);
}

ol.circle>li {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

ol.circle>li::before {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-1.73em);
  content: counter(item);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

li::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  height: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1f2c60;
  left: -2.2em;
  top: 0.05em;
  z-index: 1;
}

ol.circle ul li.example+li.example {  /* new */
  margin-top: calc(1em + 1.5vw);      /* same as line height for li */
}
```

```html
<div class="meaning">
  <ol class="circle">
    <li>Text_1
      <ul>
        <li class="example"><span>Text_2</span></li>
        <li class="example_translated"><span>Text_3</span></li>
        <li class="example"><span>Text_4</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Text_5
      <ul>
        <li class="example"><span>Text_6</span></li>

        <li class="example"><span>Text_8</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this definitely works, however when the list item is removed (Text_7 in your example) the distance between Text_6 and Text_8 is _equal_ to the height of the removed item. Solution #3 from @jigneshpanchalmj is more suitable in _my_ case, as it allows to regulate the height of the space between list items. However you've raised an interesting topic: "assigning classes to list items _directly_" VS. "assigning classes via `span` " - which is better in general and why?

Comment: So does this one! Just change the top-margin in the last CSS selector. But I thought you said the height of the empty space should be the same as one list item, so that the layoutdidn't change as the list item was added.

Comment: WRT your other question, maybe that should be a separate question. It depends onm the situation. In this particular case, there is no CSS selector that says "the li after an li containing a certain span", so I had to do it like this.